# xsel: Can't open display: (null)

Tags: x-server, xsel

I want to copy a long file into clipboard with xsel,in my local pc ,just input:

```
cat /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation|xsel -b
```

The file `mysql_secure_installation` located in my local os was copied into clipboard.

Now login to my vps with ssh command,then input

```
DISPLAY=:0 cat /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation|xsel -b
```

I come across the error info:

```
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I know that the proper way to get remote file is `scp` command:

```
scp -P port username@tohostname:/remotefile /newlocalfile
```

I just wonder how to get file content copied into clipboard after loginning my vps,copy file from remote machine to the clipboard of my local computer.

Same error:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xsel -b <  /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Connection refused
```

Comment: So you try to copy file from remote machine to the clipboard of your local computer, right?

Comment: try running it as `DISPLAY=:0 xsel -b <foo` or `... | DISPLAY=:0 xsel -b` instead of `DISPLAY=:0 cat ... | xsel -b` which will only set the `DISPLAY` envvar for the cat process.

Comment: I am getting same issue on remote server (CentOS 7) when working in screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start your `ssh` connection with

```
ssh -X yourserver
```

then *don't* change the `DISPLAY` variable yourself.  `ssh` should set it up automatically, so that `xsel` (and any other X11 clients) can use the display on your local computer -- including its clipboard.  This is called [X11 forwarding](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ForwardX11).

Manually setting `DISPLAY=:0` in your `ssh` session will tell `xsel` to use the display on that remote server -- if one is even running.

Comment: I couldn't get this working. `xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: @Ryan What is the value of `DISPLAY` when you do this?  If you enable debugging messages with `ssh -v`, does it including anything about X11 forwarding?

Comment: Interesting. I see `debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated`

Comment: Maybe you are talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39556508/470749 (I will look at my client and server configs.) I'd also asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60117294/470749

Comment: Note: if you're running tmux, make sure you _restart_ your tmux session after reconnecting to the remote host with `ssh -X`, otherwise this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

As Lord Giles [said here](https://askubuntu.com/a/305681/349837):

- Client side you need to connect with `ssh -X` (per session, `~/.ssh/config` to use it always)
- Server side you need to have `X11Forwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (note the `d`). Also, some packages like `xauth` and `libxdmcp6`, installed by default. Remember to `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service` to changes to take effect.

[For security reasons](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14817/147346), I wouldn't enable it to use it always, and in general only use it on very trusted servers.

#### Other sources

- [X11 Forwarding | Unix Wiki | Fandom](https://unix.fandom.com/wiki/X11_Forwarding)
- [XSECURITY(7) manual page](https://www.xfree86.org/current/Xsecurity.7.html)
- [Bad Security 201 – Remote X Sessions over SSH | Pat's Daily Grind](https://padraic2112.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/bad-security-201-remote-x-sessions-over-ssh/)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have shown how to forward your X session to achieve the O (outcome) desired. However, this is not very secure (as has been pointed out) or performant, and often needs additional setup.

The best way to achieve the same E (effect) in the SCROE model is to transfer the raw data bytestream to the host and locally shove it into the clipboard. You already almost had it. You had a pipe, and you had scp, but scp is only almost right.

```
ssh -p port username@tohostname cat /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation | xsel -ib
```

The pipe ensures the stdout of the `cat` command on the *remote* host ends up as stdin of the `xsel` command on the *local* host. (I also added a `-i`; xsel is used safest when the mode of operation is explicitly specified.)