# DISPLAY environment variable not set

Tags: ssh, rhel, remote, display, amazon-ec2

I am using a Amazon Linux 2 (a Fedora/Cent OS like distro) EC2 machine with the *Deep Learning AMI (Amazon Linux 2) Version 30.1* AMI.

I want to use `xclip` and `gedit` in the remote instance. But if I type in `xclip` I get

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

If I do `gedit filename` I get

```
(gedit:6012): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:18:40.117: cannot open display:
```

I have already gone through the following links:

1. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4933
2. [xsel: Can't open display: (null)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566081/xsel-cant-open-display-null)
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035903/how-can-i-get-around-using-xclip-in-the-linux-subsystem-on-win-10
4. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/error-couldnt-open-display-null-and-solution/
5. https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi
6. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/xdotool-error-can%27t-open-display-null-4175527094/
7. https://serverfault.com/questions/765606/xming-cant-open-display-error
8. https://serverfault.com/questions/425346/cant-open-display-x11-forwarding-cent-os
9. https://askubuntu.com/questions/305654/xclip-on-headless-server/305681#305681

And thus have,

1. installed `xauth`
2. manually set the environment variable DISPLAY to
   `export DISPLAY="IP_of_remote_machine:0"`
   `export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:0"`
   `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
   `export DISPLAY=localhost:0`
   When I do this I get

   ```
   (gedit:6053): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:23:36.052: cannot open display: 127.0.0.1:0
   ```
3. I have tried the `-Y` flag (`-X` is not an option cause of security, also `-X` doesn't work)
4. I have added `ForwardX11 yes` in the client side's `~/.ssh/config` and `X11Forwarding yes` in the server side's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Nothing works. Any directions?

**EDIT:**

I also watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7y-wycTrl0I) video which says that `DISPLAY` should not be hardcoded. But my `DISPLAY` is not set automatically. When I do a `echo $DISPLAY` I get nothing.

So I did a `xauth list` which gave me

```
ip-x-y-x.ec2.internal/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c84bcd904dd50f7776f667eca7a480f5
```

so I did

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

Still I get the same error.

Comment: When you use `ssh -Y user@remote` are you in some kind of terminal? What happens if you say `echo $DISPLAY` in that terminal **before** you use ssh? You shouldn't need to set DISPLAY manually, that is what the `-Y` should be doing automatically.

Comment: Try running ssh with the "-vv" option to print debugging info. Then [edit] your question to include the exact ssh command that you ran, the debugging output, and any relevant entries from your .ssh/config file.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by simply hardcoding $DISPLAY as :1,

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

in my `.bashrc` file.

I however, still don't understand why this works. Here is the output of `xauth list`

```
ip-172-31-74-230.ec2.internal:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  8a44b41e42cae52c6acd4747763bb985
ip-172-31-74-230.ec2.internal/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  8a44b41e42cae52c6acd4747763bb985
ip-172-31-74-230.ec2.internal:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  e24f36d585762b0c0fe24010b99e448d
ip-172-31-74-230.ec2.internal/unix:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  e24f36d585762b0c0fe24010b99e448d
ip-172-31-74-230.ec2.internal/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c84bcd904dd50f7776f667eca7a480f5
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DISPLAY` environment variable is exported to any x-Client program that needs the specification for the x-server on your original machine (the PC you typed in the `ssh` command on).

The way I do this these days, is to be lazy and ask the environment:

```
 $ env | grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.182.159 45462 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/28
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.182.159 45462 192.168.188.120 22
```

`SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` show you the IP address of your origin terminal.  In which case I `export` the following:

```
 $ export DISPLAY="192.168.182.159:0.0"
 $ xeyes
```

Start-up xeyes to satisfy yourself that everything is working for you.  Your display is ready to use.